# C++ treats macro as a class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, macros

In visual studio I've set configuration type as .dll instead of .exe and because of that sometimes I need to use `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` . So I've created macros for them inside header file called "Core"

```
#pragma once

#ifdef B5_PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    #ifdef B5_BUILD_DLL
        #define B5_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define B5_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif // B5_BUILD_DLL
#else
#error Bos5 only supports Windows!
#endif // B5_PLATFORM_WINDOWS
```

I have a class "Application" inside of my namespace "Bos5" which uses `BS_API`

```
#pragma once

#include "Core.h"

namespace Bos5 {
    class B5_API Application
    {
    public:
        Application();
        ~Application();
        void Run();
    };
}
```

everything works fine inside this project but when I reference this to another project for some reason visual studio thinks B5_API is a class and "Application" isn't. therefore code below doesn't compile saying namespace Bos5 doesn't have struct or class called "Application"

```
#include <FinalBos5.h>

class  Sandbox : public Bos5::Application
{
public:
    Sandbox(){}
    ~Sandbox(){}
};


int main() {
}
```

I think this image can better explain what I'm saying [image]

Comment: You need to `#include "Core.h"` so that `#define B5_API __declspec(dllimport)` happens

Comment: You're sure it doesn't compile, or you just see the red squiggles? Often editor live checks aren't as correct as the actual compiler.

Comment: I do have that inside application.h. If i were to do similar thing inside the same project where application class is declared everything works just fine

Comment: @aschepler it doesn't compile because of some other reasons too actually but I was concerned about those red squiggles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've fixed it. turns out problem was completely different thing. My preprocessor didn't save some of the definitions so in second project B5_API wasn't getting defined